# app does not run in the emulator. eclipse shows the following errors

Tags: android, android-emulator

> [2013-04-23 08:43:47 - StartupActivity] Android Launch! [2013-04-23
>   08:43:47 - StartupActivity] adb is running normally. [2013-04-23
>   08:43:47 - StartupActivity] Performing
>   com.eleybourn.bookcatalogue.StartupActivity activity launch
>   [2013-04-23 08:43:48 - StartupActivity] Automatic Target Mode:
>   launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'book' [2013-04-23 08:43:48
>   - StartupActivity] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'book' [2013-04-23 08:43:48 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in
>   use. Changes will not persist! [2013-04-23 08:43:48 - Emulator]
>   WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
>   [2013-04-23 08:43:48 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
>   [2013-04-23 08:43:48 - Emulator] could not get
>   wglGetExtensionsStringARB [2013-04-23 08:43:48 - Emulator] emulator:
>   WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software
>   renderer. [2013-04-23 08:43:48 - Emulator] could not get
>   wglGetExtensionsStringARB [2013-04-23 08:43:48 - Emulator] could not
>   get wglGetExtensionsStringARB [2013-04-23 08:43:48 - Emulator] could
>   not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB [2013-04-23 08:43:48 - Emulator]
>   could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB [2013-04-23 08:43:48 -
>   Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB [2013-04-23 08:43:48
>   - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB [2013-04-23 08:43:48 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>   [2013-04-23 08:43:48 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of
>   view and was recentered [2013-04-23 08:43:48 - Emulator]

help me rectify the error.emulator starts perfectly when i run the code but nothing happens after that and app is not found in the app tray.

Comment: try cleaning your project,then restart avd and eclipse

Comment: i created a new device and its working! thanks @KaranMer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to delete your current avd and create a new one.